# fx:controller="" in .FXML

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

is it possible to add two controllers (`fx:controller=""`) in one FXML file ?

I could managed to add only one as `fx:controller=""`

See the code

```
<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="596.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="demoapp.ClientArea">
```

Comment: It is not possible. If you can explain why you need to add two controllers,maybe we can find another solution.

Comment: I have four files ... 2 files `.java` (`ClientArea.java` and `Undecorator.java`) and 2 files `.fxml` (`ClientArea.fxml` and `Undecorator.fxml`) `ClientArea.fxml` has the `fx:controller=""` the `ClientArea.java` and `Undecorator.fxml` has the `fx:controller=""` the `Undecorator.java` I want to use what's in the `ClientArea.fxml` `Undecorator.java`

Comment: @JacksonMireski Just updated my answer, hope that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set more than one controller within an FXML file using  `(fx:controller="")`, instead consider injecting the controller manually, basically there are two ways :

Using [setController](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController%28java.lang.Object%29) method without mention the controller inside the FXML file :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
URL location = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/ClientArea.fxml");
loader.setLocation(location);   
loader.setController(new ClientArea());
// loader.setController(new Undecorator());
loader.load();
```

---

More appropriately, use [setControllerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) method :

first, make sure that both of the controllers `ClientArea`  and `Undecorator` implement an interface (`Icontroller`, containing the event Handler methods) mentioned in the `FXML` file `(fx:controller="IController")`, then choose the controller when loading your View from the `FXML` file:

```
FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
URL location = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/ClientArea.fxml");
loader.setLocation(location);
loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {   
    public Object call(Class<?> p) {
        return new ClientArea(); 
           // return new Undecorator();
    }
});
loader.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

If fits in your code, your `Undecorator.java` could extend from `ClientArea.java`. So, any method (or FXML method/control) could be used from its parent: `ClientArea.java`. Using JavaFX SceneBuilder, won't show you the package.ClientArea in the controller selection, but at runtime it will work.